# Error configuring the IMAP server using C# on Blueprism (Office 365)

Tags: c#, outlook, office365, imap, blueprism

Recently in my company we started to use Office 365 instead of the Outlook application, so we are upgrading our RPAs to this new Outlook use, in this case we're using IMAP.
We're getting some errors when trying to get connection with Office 365, the error returned from Blue Prism is "Internal : Could not execute code stage because exception thrown by code stage: The IMAP server has unexpectedly disconnected.".
This is the code that we are using now:

```
client = new ImapClient();
client.Connect("mail.company.com", 993, true);
client.Authenticate(Username, Password);
```

We already tried to change the Port to the recommended by Microsoft, changed also the TSL or SSL flag to false and the Server to "outlook.office365.com", but we're getting the same errors every time.
Do you know anything that we can do to fix this?

Comment: Did you try port 143, 220 (not secure  with TLS false) or por5t 85 (secure with TLS true)?  Talk to you ADMIN and see what port number should be used for Imap?

Comment: By default, TLS should be on, and on port 993.  (not starttls)

Comment: Make sure your admin has also enabled IMAP for users, and a protocol log would help.  Also, you probably need to use an access token or OAuth; Office365 does not or will soon not allow plain password logins.

Comment: Does not, since four months.